# Combination of function's roots question

Tags: trigonometry, combinations, roots

I have a trig function $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}x)$$ with roots at 0, 3, 6, 9. I also have a function $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}x)$$ with roots at 0, 4, 8, 12. I am looking for a generalized way to combine them as one function in a way that preserves their roots (and doesn't add any), regardless of what happens everywhere else. This is more of a question of the method rather than a specific answer. All creative answers are much appreciated!

Comment: isn't $12$ a root for the first function?

Comment: yes but the goal is to find a function with roots 0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12... or use the same method with any two functions like these

Comment: $\cos 0=1$, $\cos\pi=-1$, ... None of those are roots

Comment: That was a typo I meant sine. Sorry for the confusion but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply the two functions. You will get roots **only** when you have a root of either (or both) of those functions. Also see my comment about the roots of the cosine function.